# How to get record for user who have not purchase for last 18 months in laravel?

Tags: laravel

```
$eighteenMonthsAgo = Carbon::now()->subMonths(18);
$modelQuery = $modelQuery->whereHas('hasOrders', function ($query) use($eighteenMonthsAgo) {
$query->whereDate('order_date', '>=', $eighteenMonthsAgo);
```

I want the record for users who had not purchased for last 18 months. I wrote above code but it failed.

Answer (score 1):

Please use whereDoesntHave instead of whereHas

```
$eighteenMonthsAgo = Carbon::now()->subMonths(18);
$modelQuery = $modelQuery->with('hasOrders')->whereDoesntHave('hasOrders', function($query) use($eighteenMonthsAgo) {
    $query->whereDate('order_date', '>=', $eighteenMonthsAgo);
});
```